# NUnit can't cope with Lazy Instantiation

Tags: vb.net, nunit, lazy-initialization

I have a lazily-instantiated singleton:

```
Public Class SingletonBase(Of TDerivedClass As {SingletonBase(Of TDerivedClass)})
    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of TDerivedClass)(Function() CType(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(TDerivedClass), True), TDerivedClass), Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Using the Singleton pattern allows the config handler to be observable
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As TDerivedClass
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Then a class that implements it:

```
Public MustInherit Class ConfigurationHandlerBase(Of TDerivedConfigHandler As {SingletonBase(Of TDerivedConfigHandler)})
    Inherits SingletonBase(Of TDerivedConfigHandler)
```

and a class that implements that one:

```
Public Class ConfigHandler
    Inherits ConfigurationHandlerBase(Of ConfigHandler)
    Private _test As String
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Test as String
        Get
            Return Instance._test
        End Get
    End Property
```

I then have an NUnit project/classes:

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
<TestFixture>
Public Class ConfigHandlerTests
    <Test>
    Public Sub Test()
        Dim success As ConfigHandler = ConfigHandler.Instance ' this works
        Dim fail as String = ConfigHandler.Test ' this fails!!!
```

The error I get when **Running** the test is a `NullReferenceException`, and **debugging** the test, when it gets into the Getter of the property (`Dim test As Boolean = ConfigHandler.Instance._test`), hovering over `Instance` *sometimes* gives me the following error:

> 'Instance' threw an exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'

Always if I try to step into that line of code, the test ends with the following stack trace:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.MethodWrapper.Invoke(Object fixture, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunNonAsyncTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
   at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.BeforeAndAfterTestCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
Result Message: Test cancelled by user
```

I'm assuming that Nunit isn't playing nice with `Lazy` -- but does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: There is nothing NUnit specific in the test code that is failing except for the fact that it is running in a test. Other than the thread it is running on, it is no different than running the equivalent code in Main in a console app. Have you tried factoring NUnit out and just running the same code elsewhere?

Comment: Is there a typo in the title? Should "copy" be "cope"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was going off on a red-herring. The simple answer was that I needed the config items to be in the config file of the NUnit project, not the main project.